# CakePHP 3 change locale input date

Tags: date, internationalization, locale, cakephp-3.0

I have the following input date on form:

```
echo $this->Form->input('fecha_limite', ['label' => __('Fecha límite'), 'type' => 'date', 'class' => 'form-control']);
```

By default the months are shown on english locale and I want to establish spanish locale. 
I have tried to change it using `intl.default_locale` since config/bootstrap.php and using `I18n::locale()` and doesn't works...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you translated the messages (month names) in the appropriate language file for the given locale?

Comment: Now it works, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this problem probably has some Reason.cakephp 3 has cache for i18n therefore you must delete cache .maybe you was a mistake in file locale.you have to don't use of two line in that file.

However maybe because of use form helper.please test outside form helper